# Which test element is used to apply test execution settings for the main business flow excluding Login and Log out

Tags: jmeter

Which test element is used to apply test execution settings for the main business flow excluding Login and Log out

1) Run time controller
2) Loop controller
3) Transaction controller
4) Throughput controller

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go for the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/) because it is used for "grouping" its children and report their cumulative execution time as one business "transaction".

The others are:

- [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) - sets maximum execution duration for its children
- [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) - it's children will be executed specified number of times
- [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - can be used to distribute certain actions, i.e. 20% of users do this, 30% of users do that and remaining do something else.